# Make a Toolbar have a grid layout

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I want to make a `QToolBar` have 3 columns of buttons when docked on the left side of the `QMainWindow`, but have 1 row when docked on the top of the main window. Is this possible?

I have a tried using a `QToolBar` with a custom layout, but the normal re-size behavior of the `QToolBar` doesn’t work (doesn’t hide widgets behind an expand button when its too small). The non-working expand button isn’t that big of a deal, but the bigger problem is that the custom layout prevents the main window from being smaller than the toolbar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to get my desired behavior by putting each row of Tool Buttons in a `QHBoxLayout`, putting that layout in a empty `QWidget`, and calling `toolBar->addWidget( widget )` for each row.  This gives me a grid toolbar when the toolbar is mounted on the left, and single horizontal bar when mounted on the top.

Comment: Glad you did it! Could you share some images about it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I can share any images.  But I can describe how it behaves.  The toolbar, when docked on the left, is a grid with 3 columns and several rows.  When i shrink the window vertically so that the toolbar doesn't have enough room, the the rows of buttons will start disappearing behind the normal QT "expand" button.  When you click the expand button, the hidden rows will appear, although slightly odd looking because they are still grouped in 3's.

Comment: When the toolbar is docked on the top, it looks and behaves almost exactly like a normal toolbar, the only exception being that when the main window is shrunk horizontally, the buttons will start collapsing in groups of 3, instead of 1 at a time.